# Best way to calculate “distance” between two segments expressing study participants' probability estimations

Tags: r, probability

I am working on a task in which participants estimate the probability that a series of beads are extracted from one of two hidden jars. The beads are extracted one by one, with replacement.

The two jars contain beads in two colors, yellow and black, in different proportions. *Jar A contains 85% yellow beads and 15% black beads, and jar B contains 85% black beads and 15% yellow beads.*

[image]

While the jars are hidden to the participant, he or she is aware of the difference between them - therefore he or she can estimate the probability that a sequence of beads is extracted specifically from one of the two jars.

**General Example**

After each extraction, the participant always answers the same question: "What's the probability that the sequence was extracted from jar A?

Then, if the first bead extracted is yellow, it's more likely that bead was extracted from jar A; if the second bead is also yellow, it's now even more likely that the sequence of beads was extracted from jar A, and so on.

The estimation, of course, changes as the participant is shown more beads. All participants are shown the same sequence.

**Actual Task**

At "Event 0," the participant is asked the question before seeing any beads. This is why the estimation is at .5.

Then, at Event 1, the participant is shown *a whole sequence of beads* that have already been extracted. In this case, 8 yellow beads and 2 black beads.

[image]

That's why, at this point (Event 1), the sequence is most likely coming from jar A.

After that, the participant is shown more beads, *now extracted one by one*. They all happen to be black (the participant does not know this beforehand, of course.) That's why the probability estimation slowly decreases.

Final sequence:

[image]

You can see below, the red line, as the probability estimations from one participant. On the x-axis, you can see the extraction number, on the y-axis the probability estimation.
In black you can see the ideal observer's estimation, that is, the correct probabilities.

**R Plot**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# participant's probability estimations

participant <- structure(list(event = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), prob_est = c(0.46, 
 0.98, 0.89, 0.72, 0.53, 0.21, 0.24, 0.12, 0.09, 0.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

# ideal observer's probability estimations

ideal_observer <- structure(list(event = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), prob = c(0.5, 
0.99996979903057, 0.999828885289768, 0.999031123657329, 0.994534412955466, 
0.969798657718121, 0.85, 0.5, 0.15, 0.0302013422818792)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

plot <- ggplot(data=subset(participant, event<=9), aes(x = event, y = prob_est, col="red"))  + 
        geom_point(cex=1.5)+
        geom_line(lwd=0.9)+
        labs(x="Event Number", y="Probability") + 
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10), limits = c(0,1))+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10))+
        geom_line(data=subset(ideal_observer, event<=9), aes(x = event, y = prob),col="black",lwd=0.9)+
        geom_point(data=subset(ideal_observer, event<=9), aes(x = event, y = prob),col="black",cex=1.5)
plot
```

[image]

**The problem**

I would like to define a "profile" for each participant, based on how he or she responds to the task. I would like to have a good idea of how much he or she is far off from the ideal observer. I thought I could just calculate the distance between each pair of points on the y-axis and sum them up.

```r
# calculating discrepancy from ideal performance
difference <-  sum(participant[,2] - ideal_observer[,2])
difference
#> [1] -2.743364
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Question**

Does this make sense? I was wondering if there are better ways to perform this type of analysis. Is there a way I can retain more information about the participant's choices? For example, I thought I could fit one curve to the participant's response and one curve to the ideal observer's estimation and evaluate the difference between the parameters defining the curves, but I am not sure about how to go about that.

By the way, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVMSq.png) you can see an image of all the participants.

Comment: I think you would want to use something other than the pure difference, as I could be off by 0.5 on my first guess and -0.5 on my second guess and I'd look perfect. Perhaps using the absolute difference or squared difference would be a starting point.

Comment: @bouncyball thanks, that's a good point. But then how to distinguish whether a participant is overestimating or underestimating probabilities? Maybe together with the squared difference, I could keep track of the sign of the difference at each extraction, and create an index based on how many times participants underestimate or overestimate probabilities.

Comment: I don't get the experiment (example would help), but regardless, if your aim is to "profile" users, I'm not sure a total/avg loss is the way to go as you are reducing a behaviour to 1 number (you could have != estimations leading to the same score) . Alternative: consider each event as a dimension and estimates as values for those dimensions, and do some clustering in that n-dimensional space. This might yield profiles more useful to understanding behaviour than 1 single number (ppl similar to ideal observer, ppl who suck, ppl who start bad but get better etc...)

Comment: Similar idea, but instead of considering each event as separate dimension, consider the whole series of estimations as time series data and do clustering on that: https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/clustering/plot_kmeans.html#a-note-on-pre-processing

Comment: Thank you @Max, by the way, I have rewritten the description of the task and added an example.

Comment: What I don't understand is if `estimate the probability that a series of beads are extracted from one of two hidden jars`, then isn't it a 50/50 chance of guessing the correct jar? Thus I don't understand those probabilities close to 0. Also if jars contain 1 color in majority, then I would expect the curve shape to be reversed: the more beads we draw, the more present the majority color should be, thus the more confident we can be that it's from the corresponding jar

Comment: @Max, I have edited the question again... The participant is asked about the probability that the sequence comes from a *specific* jar. If jar A contains a majority of red beads, and the sequence has also a majority of red beads, it will be more likely that the sequence comes from jar A, for example. But then, if I keep extracting beads and they are now all blue, the probability that the sequence comes from jar A will decrease.

Comment: @Emy: precisely my point. The more beads we draw, the more confident we should be about our prediction correct? If so I don't understand the decreasing probability of the chart. Anyways, it doesn't matter for the question itself, bottom line: you can't sum up behaviour to 1 number, you inevitably lose information, hence why I think looking at all the predictions will yield more satisfactory results.

Comment: @Max, right, but the evidence can also be disconfirmatory, which is what happens in this case.

Comment: @Max - I have edited the question and added pictures for clarity.